# Is there a way to disable array bounds checking in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I'm working on improving the performance of a python program, and I was wondering if there was a way to improve performance by disabling array bounds checking?  I know that some versions of Pascal let you do this.  Does python have any such feature?

I know that Python isn't really designed for high performance, but I'd like to know if it's possible to improve performance in this manner; otherwise yes, I am aware that switching to C would be faster.

Comment: No, Python does not. Also 1) the primitive sequence in in Python is a 'list', not an array; 2) if rewriting the code in C, perhaps a CPython extension, would be faster depends a good bit on the code and hotspots.. the speed advantage (if any and when avoiding Python types) would be due to bare-metal execution, not bypassing bounds checks.

Comment: Have you profiled the code? You may find that there are alternatives that would speed up your code. To me this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Not all programs written in Python will be significantly faster in C.

Comment: Bounds checking is a pretty small part of Python's overhead; eliminating bounds checking won't do much for you.

Comment: I suggest that you profile your code to find where its performance is unsatisfactory. Even if the problem is array bounds checking, which you can't disable anyway, would you really want to turn that off? Rather than clutching at straws, identify those parts of your program that are causing whatever performance problem you have.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comments and the insight guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ordinary lists, no. However, you can create your own datastructures / functions in C or C++ using the Python C API (see [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)), which you could use to implement a `dangerous_unchecked_list` data structure that behaves like a regular list but without this checking (or some other higher level data structure that needs to bypass bounds-checking internally). For much larger operations that can't be implemented optimally in Python, you could also use interprocess communication (IPC) -- as opposed to the C API -- for invoking a non-Python implementation.

However, before going down this route, you should make sure that this is truly the performance bottleneck. You may find that there are other areas where you can get bigger wins, such as by using a better algorithm, by choosing other functions or datastructures to implement natively that actually are the peformance bottleneck, by precomputing and/or caching information, or by some other means.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling array bounds checking cannot be done in Python as far as I know. 
It can, however, be done in [cython](http://cython.org/) fairly easily with the directive

```
#cython: boundscheck=False
```

However, since "premature optimization is the root of all evil." (Knuth), you might want to first check if your script runs faster by switching to [pypy](http://pypy.org/) instead of python.